# How to disable changing email in Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to display email address without possibility to replace it. And without arrow. How to disable this arrow icon? I cannot post an image, unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```